# How to identify a specific XmlNode in XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlnode

My code is storing and passing round `XmlNode` objects, there is a lot of unnecessary overhead in doing this.
I'd like to use a unique `string` or `int` instead to identify specific nodes within an `XmlDocument` and then retrieve that node later when required.

How can I do this?

I was hoping for something like:

```
    ...
    int nodeId = node.Id;
    ...
    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.GetNodeFromId(nodeId);
    ...
```

Note that there may be several nodes with the same name and path representaion.

Comment: Unclear. XmlNodes are tightly coupled to their owner, so unless you have a Clone() method (then show it), you can only pass and store object references. Cheaper and faster than an Id.

Comment: @bommelding Not sure I understand your comment, can you explain a bit more what you mean by tightly coupled

Comment: @userSteve - you should show how you 'store' XmlNodes and why you think there is any overhead. Because there probably isn't. Look up "object references".